# Python bytearray ignoring encoding?

Tags: python

I've got a chunk of code that reads binary data off a string buffer (`StringIO` object), and tries to  convert it to a `bytearray` object, but it's throwing errors when the value is greater than 127, which the ascii encoding can't handle, even when I'm trying to override it:

```
file = open(filename, 'r+b')
file.seek(offset)
chunk = file.read(length)
chunk = zlib.decompress(chunk)
chunk = StringIO(chunk)

d = bytearray(chunk.read(10), encoding="iso8859-1", errors="replace")
```

Running that code gives me:

```
  d = bytearray(chunk.read(10), encoding="iso8859-1", errors="replace")
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf0 in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Obviously 240 (decimal of 0xf0) can't fit in the ascii encoding range, but that's why I'm explicitly setting the encoding. But it seems to be ignoring it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When converting a string to another encoding, its original encoding is taken to be ASCII if it is a `str` or Unicode if it is a `unicode` object. When creating the `bytearray`, the `encoding` parameter is required only if the string is `unicode`. Just don't specify an encoding and you will get the results you want.

Comment: If that just was documented properly (instead of just saying `"If it is a string, you must also give the encoding (and optionally, errors) parameters; bytearray() then converts the string to bytes using str.encode()."` for both Python 2.7 and 3)..

Comment: er; nitpick.  "unicode" is not an encoding, and `unicode` is not encoded;  the way I would phrase it is that when converting to bytes, you must have a `unicode` object to encode, if you use a `str`, it's first *decode*ed from ascii, into a 'temporary' unicode object, and that is then encoded as requested.

Answer (score 2):

I am not quite sure what the problem is.

StringIO is for string IO, not for binary IO.
If you want to get a bytearray representing the whole content of the file, use:

```
with open ('filename', 'r') as file: bytes = bytearray (file.read () )
```

if you want to get a string with only ascii characters contained in that file, use:

```
with open ('filename', 'r') as file: asciis = file.read ().decode ('ascii', 'ignore')
```

(If you run it on windows, you will probably need the binary flag for opening the file.

Comment: `file.read()` also returns a string, so this isn't the problem.

Comment: It works for me to read a file with arbitrary binary data and print bytes yields all the bytes, no matter if < or > 127.